# Flask render_template not able to work in Python, and jinja2 codes not working

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I have 2 html files which are index.html and registration.html, I think the problem comes in the index.html and the server.py.

This is my codes for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Registeration</title></head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome!xxx registeration below</h2>
    <table>
        <form action="{{url_for('form')}}" method="POST">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td><input type="text" id="name"></td>
        </tr>            
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td><td><input type="text" id="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PhoneNumber</td><td><input type="text" id="phonenumber"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address</td><td><input type="text" id="address"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button>Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my codes for my python codes server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("Registration.db")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/form', methods=["POST"])
def form():
    name = request.form.get("name")
    email = request.form.get("email")
    phonenumber = request.form.get("phonenumber")
    address = request.form.get("address")

    con.execute("INSERT INTO Registration(Name, Email, Phonenumber, Address) " +
                "VALUES(?,?,?,?)", (name,email,phonenumber,address))
    
    cursor = con.execute("SELECT Name, Email, Phonenumber, Address FROM Registration")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    return render_template("registration.html", data = rows)

app.run(debug=True, port=5000)

con.commit()
con.close()
```

When I tried to run these files, I managed to successfully run the index.html file. However, when I press the Submit button, the website prompt "Your file couldn’t be accessed" and shows a web name as such

file:///C:/Users/123456789/Desktop/Computing%20language/HTML/Registration/templates/%7B%7Burl_for('form')%7D%7D

I have searched online, most said its because people didn't use flask to render_template, which is not my case. Some said that it's due to something related to the parent folder of the 'templates' folder which I can't really understand about it.

Also, my jinja2 codes in my registration.html does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Registration_list</title></head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Phonenumber</th><th>Address</th>
        </tr>
        {% if list != [] %}
            {% for row in data %}
            <tr><td>{% row[0] %}</td><td>{% row[1] %}</td><td>{% row[2] %}</td><td>{% row[3] %}</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </table>
    <a href="C:\Users\ling131031003\Desktop\Computing language\HTML\Registration\templates\index.html">Submit another form</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If I enter the registration.html method through 'POST' method, it will appear the error above.
However, if I use "GET" method to enter into the registration.html, I managed to enter the registration.html, but it will display the jinja2 codes as text instead of functional codes.

I really cannot figure out what when wrong with my codes

Comment: I'd start by having a look at the HTML produced by `'/'`. Open it in your browser, right click and choose "View Page Source" (or similar). I suspect your `url_for` doesn't quite do what you think it does...

Comment: @Jeronimo Hi, sorry for the late reply. I've "View Page Source", and the code is the same as what I wrote.

Comment: If it rendered correctly, it should have filled in the `url_for` part with something...